# Marshall JSON in NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js

I have huge JSON as part of the REST request and want to marshall/unmarshall the JSON in NodeJS.  I see that I can use JSON.parse to parse the JSON.

If I want to write the JSON, JSON.stringfy is available. But for huge JSON, this becomes very complicate.

I am looking for something like [jackson-json](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) in nodejs, where I can represent JSON schema/structure and store/manipulate the JSON in memory.

After I searched for long time, I found [json-typescript-mapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-typescript-mapper). Is this the only way, where I can marshall/unmarshall json into equivalent objects in memory ? Is this the best practice to for JSON marshalling/unmarshalling in nodejs ?

Regards,
Albie Morken

Answer (score 2):

The best practice for marshall/unmarshall JSON in Javascript is `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse` as you mentioned. Javascript is untyped language so there is sadly/luckily no need for a class definition the JSON is mapped onto like it's in Jackson. You can still use [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) or [Flow](https://flow.org/) for type  checking.

If the JSON is huge and you're afraid that parsing will consume a lot of resources you can work with it like a node stream https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html.
 Node 10 will have support for async iteration over streams http://2ality.com/2018/04/async-iter-nodejs.html

Comment: A quick observation - this answer is accurate apart from the TypeScript part. Unmarshalling JSON doesn't create objects in their right class - is simply creates generic objects and TypeScript doesn't complain about it.